# Firebase automatic screen reporting not working

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-analytics

I used to see the screen view events attached to my app crashes on Firebase but not anymore; however, I got the following log when the app starts.

> Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:FIREventScreenView parameters:] to log a screen view event. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist

usually, I was able to see before all the UIViewController that has been pushed inside the log tab of the crash but now I see only the custom ones

[image]

I set the `FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled` flag to true in the info.plist file and I updated my pods to the latest version and still have the same issue.

```
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics' , '8.6.0'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics' , '8.6.0'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging' , '8.6.0'
```

Any idea what is missing here?

Comment: Why do you mean by "Firebase automatic screen reporting not working"?  Show your code in AppDelegate.

Comment: @ElTomato I mean all UIViewControllers that are pushed (I have updated my question and added a screenshot)